# How can I simulate logging out after using Passport::actingAs in a unit or integration test?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

I have a test where I simulate logging in, then afterwards I want to test things as if I was not logged in. Like so.

```
// log in as user with id 2
$id = 2;
Passport::actingAs(User::findOrFail($id));
testSomeStuff()
...
// now I want to test things as if I was not logged in
```

Is there a way to do this in one test function? I'm using Laravel 5.6 and Passport 5.

Comment: Maybe try `Auth::logout()`?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem. Getting the error: Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::logout does not exist.

Comment: @Shadrix I don't think I did.

Comment: I had the same issue and could not come up with a solution, and I like to think I tried them all. It would be great to have a way to cancel the '$this->actingAs($this->user);' Anyway...the only suggestion I have is to do all your unauthorised tests at the start of your test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your test

```
$this->refreshApplication();
```

Had the same issue and this is the only thing that worked for me

EDIT: It seems to clear out the database also. Calling the logout endpoint directly seems to work too.

```
$this->actingAs($user)->get('/logout');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work:

```php
Auth::logout();
```

Don't for get to set `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` above your test class.